# How to convert the json to a document object for DocumentAI

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

Using a general form parser, i want to fetch the entities and append those to the document object. (for a general form parser-- there are no properties called "entities", so need to create one)

though i am using to_json() to convert the document object to json object, similarly, is there any function to reverse this operation like converting the json object to the document object.

```
doc_json=documentai.Document.to_json(result.document)
   
my_image = json.loads(doc_json)

my_dict={}
my_dict['textAnchor']=result.document.pages[0].form_fields[0].field_value.text_anchor  //creating entities

my_list.append(my_dict)


my_image['entities']=my_list

toDoc=json.dumps(my_image)
```

Getting an error "TypeError: Object of type TextAnchor is not JSON serializable"

I did try the following

1. added to json for the result json
   but still its not making serialisable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another method. `documentai.Document.from_json(json_as_string)` There is also `documentai.Document.from_dict(document_as_dict)`.

It seems like the issue is how you're trying to convert the form fields into entities. Is there a reason you're trying to do this?

It would likely make more sense to extract the form fields as shown in [Handle the processing response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables) and keep them as Form Fields.

Note: The newest version of the Form Parser [`pretrained-form-parser-v2.0-2022-11-10`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser:%7E:text=pretrained%2Dform%2Dparser%2Dv2.0%2D2022%2D11%2D10) supports generic entity extraction, so this might serve your use case.

If you're having difficulty with managing the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) object output, you can also try using the [Document AI Toolbox SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#toolbox) which has a simpler interface for reading common fields.

Comment: yes there exist a reason for doing this,
 i want to reduce the "human in the loop" work to as minimal as possible and want to train the documents in the custom document extractor, therefore, i am sending the document to the form-parser and retrieving the entities from the ["pages"]["formFields]  (explicitly as the entities list is empty) and manually retrieving "textAnchor", "confidence", "boundingPolyForDemoFrontEnd", "mentionText" and "type" 

Thanks,

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. You're trying to do reverse-annotation using the Form Parser.

I just added a Notebook to the document-ai-samples repository that does what you're trying to do. It's designed for a specific dataset, and it also includes the batch processing of the documents but most of the concepts should transfer over. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/document-ai-samples/tree/main/form-parser-to-cde